# Why does a plastic comb attracts tiny bits of paper if it is an insulator?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, insulators

When we rub plastic comb against dry hair, it attracts tiny bits of paper. We know that plastic comb is an insulator of electricity but then how is it getting charged and showing the property of attracting?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does a neutral particle feel the electric pull](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317980/does-a-neutral-particle-feel-the-electric-pull), [Why does the comb attract the pieces of paper if they're neutral?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63557/why-does-the-comb-attract-the-pieces-of-papers-if-theyre-neutral)

Answer (score 0):

because of *electrostatic forces* acting on it. 
when we rub the plastic comb it will either be charged *negatively or positively.*
it will induce negative charges on the bits of paper if the comb is positively charged so, the bits of paper will be *attracted* by the plastic comb which is **an insulator**